# Poor performance executing "cp -al" over a NFS export

Tags: performance, nfs, linux-networking

I am in the process of implementing a backup of a WD My Book Live Duo. This device is configured with software RAID0. The backup source directory is the root of the device, and the destination is a directory inside the same filesystem (taking appropriate care to avoid recursive copy of the backup files themselves). There is a layer of encryption for backup files (source files are clear text), what requires more computation power than that the NAS is able to deliver. Because of this, CPU-consuming opperations are carried out in a server that is in the same network.

The NAS is exporting two directories through NFS. One is read-only and contains the whole filesystem (it is the backup source), and the other is read-write (it is the backup root). Configuration details are stated at the end of the post.

The backup server uses `encfs` as encryption layer and `rsnapshot` to carry out the backup itself.

**The problem is:** The first step of the backup, which consists in a `cp -al` of the last backup directory into a new directory, is taking about two hours to complete.

I have performed the following tests in the NFS server side so far:

- The same `cp -al` operation takes five minutes if executed directly in the NAS
- `dd /dev/zero ~/test.tmp` shows a throughput very close to 100 MiB/s
- `top` shows low CPU consumption. However, *load average* is high (~4)
- `iperf` transfer rate is 1.000 Mpbs, so the network link is performing at the expected full capacity
- `vmstat 1` shows very high *wa* (waiting for IO) values (~80-90%)
- Setting MTU to 9000 (tested with `ping -M do mybackup`) didn't seem to have any effect
- Exporting with `async` didn't seem to have any effect

The following tests have been carried out in the NFS client side:

- `dd /dev/zero /e/test.tmp` (encrypted) shows the same throughput as `dd /dev/zero /b` (unencrypted). So the encryption layer doesn't seem to be the problem. The transfer rate is ~30 MiB/s, which is quite low, tough. Using SMB to perform this test yields simmilar results
- `top` shows low CPU consumption. *load average* is below 2 (the server has 2 cores)
- `vmstat 1` shows that the system is almost idle
- Setting `tcp,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768` mount options didn't seem to have any effect

**Configuration files**

*NFS Server*

```
# /etc/exports

# 'mybackup' is the name of the backup server
/               mybackup(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,crossmnt)

# This export has to be explicitly declared to enable clients to access /DataVolume/b
/DataVolume     mybackup(ro,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)

# This is the backup root.
/DataVolume/b   mybackup(rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

*NFS Client*

```
# /etc/fstab

# 'ewnas' is the name of the NAS
ewnas:/                 /r      nfs     auto,noatime,tcp,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768    0       0
ewnas:/DataVolume/b     /b      nfs     auto,noatime,tcp,hard,intr,nfsvers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768    0       0
```

I've been stuck with this for several days now. Any contribution will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Guillermo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rsync to see if performance is better?

`rsync -Paz --exclude-from 'rsync-exclude.txt' fromssh@server:path tossh@server:path`

[Reference discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349613/how-to-exclude-a-folder-from-rsync)

Comment: Close. I changed my `rsnapshot` configuration to make it use its native `cp` implementation instead of system `cp` command (this is, I removed `cmd_cp` and `cmd_du` options). The backup process took only 10 minutes! I'm accepting your answer as a solution for giving the idea of using a different implemntation of `cp`. BTW, in `rsync`, source and destination parameters cannot both be remote...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the rsync. Another option I found in some research was netcat. Glad you were able to sort it out though and thanks for the points!